# Dynamically Determine Android Resources

Tags: android, android-resources

I have a number of different string resource files that are built with my Android application using our build system. These string files can be added incrementally at any time and our build system will pick them up from their separate directory.  I want to enumerate all of the string files or be able to obtain a single string in them without having to know the name or id of the string resource in them. I also don't want the person adding these to have to edit a main string file in my package that includes an array listing the different files. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Example:

```
SoccerStrings.xml
   id="SoccerDetails" value="soccer"
CricketStrings.xml
   id="CricketDetails" value="cricket"
```

Without knowing these files exist how can I provide a list view with two items: Cricket and Soccer in addition to automatically supporting any additional files that might appear.

I was thinking the best possible approach would be to have the build system pull the individual files under assets folder and then use the getAssets().list("") functionality along with the XMLResourceParser class to access the string values.  Would this work and allow me to have id conflicts (ex: id="name")?  Is there an easier way?

Comment: Is there a way to add to an existing string array in a different string resource file?

Comment: I just determined I can use reflection to get the fields for R.string but it seems really ugly.  Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Reflection is also slow on android.  The code to do it is only a few lines, though.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at `aapt`.  I know you can get the resources out of the .apk with the following command --

```
aapt d --values resources app.apk
```

It might be possible to use aapt to get the resources earlier in the build process.  It has the following option which looks prosmising, but aapt documentation is a bit thin.

```
--output-text-symbols
   Generates a text file containing the resource symbols of the R class in the
   specified folder.
```

As another alternative, you could modify your build process and parse the string class directly out of the `gen/<package>/R.java file` after it has been generated.  You could store that in a loadable file, or generate your own source file to add to the build.

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to tell you how to do it. I am answering the question to advise against it.

What you are planning to do does not go well with the resource files. These files are basically code. What you want to do is about data. You should have your data in assets directory. Then these files won't be precompiled in your build like the resource file. You can process these files any way you want. There will be then quite a bit coding involved to convert all that into business logic, but that would be price to pay to write good, maintainable code.

Playing with resource files the way you are suggesting is akin to Java reflection. You want to use it only because you have functionality that is about such feature, not because it's the easiest way out.

Having said that, you might be exactly in a situation where you have to handle the resource files the way you stated. In that case, please accept my apologies.